# An interesting problem from Iran MO

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

This year there was an interesting question in 3rd round of the Iran math olympiad:

Assume that we want to tile a $n\times n$ table with $1\times 1,1\times 2,\cdots,1\times n$ tiles.
Assume that someone gives us some tiles of these types such that the sum of their area is at least $n^2$. Let $f(n)$ be the biggest number that we can cover an area of $f(n)$ with these tiles independent of what tiles the other person gives us. Prove that $$n^2-\lceil n^2/4\rceil\le f(n)\le n^2-\lfloor n^2/8\rfloor$$
(Tiles should not overlap, and the other person can give us several tiles of the same type.)

There  is still a big gap between these bounds, can someone give a better bound for $f(n)$ at least for big enough $n$?

Comment: Have the tiles to be placed with their sides parallel to the sides of the square?

Comment: A good way to start to solve similar problems can be to calculate $f(n)$ for small values of $n$.